# Recover dpkg dialog from interrupted SSH connection

Tags: dpkg

I forget to use tmux or screen during a `apt-get install` command, and SSH connection suddenly closed due to network issue.

How can I get back to the dpkg dialog that is still running?

From ps command there's a status-fd in dpkg, so there might be a way to open the dialog?

```
/usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 54 --no-triggers --unpack --auto-deconfigure --recursive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-JPVchq
```